# How to list all the objects in response to a query using cloudant java client?

Tags: java, cloudant

I am using cloudant-client 2.17.0. I have a partitioned db and want to make a query to get all the documents which match it.

com.cloudant.client.api.Database class's query methods returns a QueryResult object, which has bookmark field in it. I cannot find any query method which takes this bookmark as argument. So do all the query methods (of com.cloudant.client.api.Database) by default return all the documents or is there a query method somewhere which takes this bookmark as argument? If there is such method, how do I get the page size? Cloudant doc mentions, right way to check if a certain page is the last page of result is to check if the result size < page size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the bookmark in `QueryBuilder` helper class and pass that to the Database `query` method.
Here's a QueryBuilder example from the [java-cloudant API documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/2.17.0):

```
 QueryBuilder queryBuilder = db.query(new QueryBuilder(and(
   gt("Movie_year", 1960),
   eq("Person_name", "Alec Guinness"))).
   sort(Sort.desc("Movie_year")).
   fields("Movie_name", "Movie_year").
   bookmark("some-bookmark").
   limit(2);
```

Then you'd pass the `query` variable to `db.query` where `db` is `com.cloudant.client.api.Database`

```
QueryResult<Movie> moviesPage = db.query(queryBuilder.build(), Movie.class);
```

This test case shows how to use `bookmark` to get all docs per page: https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/blob/master/cloudant-client/src/test/java/com/cloudant/tests/IndexTests.java#L254-L278.

Comment: Thank you, Esteban! I saw a note on cloudant documentation on not to rely on the bookmark to decide if there are more documents: `The presence of a bookmark doesn’t guarantee more results. You can test whether you are at the end of the result set by comparing the number of results that are returned with the page size requested. If the results returned < limit, no more results were returned in the result set.` -Is there a way I can get the page size from the query response? or do I assume 25, as is mentioned from docs or maybe just send a query with custom limit that way I always know the size?

Comment: Just a comment: I think the test case mentioned by you should have the termination condition : `(!moviesPage.getDocs()<2);`, because if I understand the doc correctly, cloudant might return a bookmark even though there are no more results to fetch, so in this edge case, the test code will end up querying +1 time.

Comment: Yes, you can control the page size using the `limit`, but for partitioned DBs it is capped at `2000` (or `200` if using text searching) [as documented here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant/offerings?topic=cloudant-limits)